# How do I fix import error in billboard.js

Tags: vuejs3, billboard.js

I'm switching from the c3 package to billboard.js in a Vue 3 application.  When I run the application, I get the following error:

> [billboard.js] Please, make sure if spline module has been imported
> and specified correctly.

As far as I can see, the spline module is being imported correctly.  Here is how the import is being done:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import bb, { area, bar, zoom, areaSpline, areaSplineRange, spline } from 'billboard.js';
```

When calling the `generate()` function, the config being passed contains:

```
type: 'spline'
```

What do I need to do to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the problem was that the spline module wasn't being loaded because I wasn't using any of the functions in that module.  To fix this, all I had to do was call the `spline()` function within the data block being passed to the `generate()` function.  So, instead of passing:

```
type: "spline"
```

I just needed to call the `spline()` function (which returns `"spline"`) as in:

```
type: spline()
```